# Returning count of perfect squared

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below prints out the numbers that are perfect squares. I am having trouble displaying the amount of perfect squares I have in my list. It should return 3.

```
squares( [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]])
```

The implementation is below:

```
def squares(square):
    for row in square:
        for col in row:
            if col**0.5%1 ==0:
                print(col)
```

Comment: `len([i for row in squares_list for i in row if i**0.5%1 == 0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.  Accumulate your perfect squares in a list and finally print the length of the list and its contents as below:

```
def squares(square):
    result = []
    for row in square:
        for col in row:
            if col**0.5%1 ==0:
                result.append(col)
    print(f'There are {len(result)} perfect squares: {result}')

squares( [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]])
#Prints: There are 3 perfect squares: [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about using an accumulator. This has helped with returning the number of perfect squares.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list comprehension as :

`len([x for row in square_list for x in row if math.sqrt(x)%1==0])`

or you can use the normal function :

```
import math
def squares(square_list):
  count = 0
  for row in square_list:
    for col in row:
      if math.sqrt(col)%1 ==0:
        count+=1
  return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save count of correct outcomes (`count`)

```
def squares(square):
    count = 0
    for row in square:
        for col in row:
            if col**0.5%1 ==0:
                count+=1
    return count
```

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance with my code.